# Better approach to create react-redux layout header component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm going to create a large scale application with react and redux and start to build the header component of the layout very first time. The layout header will have 4 child parts.

**1.** Icon that will show all the online users after clicking on it

**2.** Icon that will show latest 10 notifications after clicking on it

**3.** Icon that will show latest 10 messages received after clicking on it

**4.** Logged in  user name that will be dropdown button to show some "My profile, logout, account setting" navigation links.

As I've read about redux at so many places that we must have as less as possible stateful components. So by keeping this concept in mind, I thought to have only one header smart container with a header state consisting default states for all icons like 
`{headerOnlineUsers:[], headerMessages:[], headerNotifications:[]}`.

So if I follow the redux best practice and create only one smart header container with 4 different dumb components, the each and every time the state of any of them is changed, the whole header container will get re-rendered.
But I want to re-render only the state changed component.

**For example, If I get a user joining the chat through websocket, It will dispatch an action and the reducer will update the headerOnlineUsers list of the state. But In this case I want my only online users component to be re-render not the whole header container.**

Can anybody please suggest me the best approach to implement this kind of layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not go for your option, but would prefer a more granular approach.

- What if you split the header in 2 later on, or want to display the button somewhere else ?
- What if you have another version of your header for a subsection of the website ? You would need another container that gather again all the info.

The logic in general in redux is to separate what is data-sensitive and what is not. Your individual lists are data sensitive, the header in itself has no reason to be so far. What's more, if you want to attach actions to the icons it will quickly become messy to bring back thoses actions to the header and then its container, and even messier if you ever need to move them.

The way I would do it (and the way I do it right now as I halso develop quite huge app with react and redux), would be to have a store with those 3 lists of items, and then 3 containers, one for each icon/dropdown that links one aprticular list to the component.

Then the header is just a stateless function holding all the containers together. This way if you ever need to move one button somewhere else or reuse it, you just import the container and voila!

Comment: Thanks got it. You mean to say the outer header component will be a dumb having the inner parts as smart redux container. Right?

Comment: Exactly, this way you don't have to handle events and props transmission between the Header and its children, a fastiduous task that does not bring any value and reduce reusability.

Answer (score 0):

React.js will take care of only re-rendering what is required. So this problem is already solved for you :-)

What you plan to do sounds sane to me, I just would change one bit: The smart header container should not use internal state. Instead, your redux store should look like this:

```
{headerOnlineUsers:[], headerMessages:[], headerNotifications:[]}
```

and you should pass the redux store into the smart header container (have a look at the `connect` function in the redux documentation). This way, you can use the redux store contents in your component via `this.props`, and that's it.